# Paint? Extrude?

Tags: materials, extrude

I'm relatively new to blender and though i find a lot of it quite intuitive, there is much i have to learn. My project is the Musical Box from Camberwick Green (many under 40 and not raised in UK will not remember this BBC childrens programme), it is a hexagonal box with small skirts extruding from the top and bottom, an isolated image of one skirt below.[image]

what i want to do is decorate the outward facing faces with a kind of gold fluting...? A rough example of which is in the second pic.[image]

Is there a way i can do this by drawing it on the main face and extruding it, so that it has a little thickness and looks like it has been pasted on like a piece of card? or is there some other way? Also how could i duplicate so that it matches up evenly on all outer faces? Sorry if I'm in the wrong place to ask this, but maybe somebody could even point me in the direction of a tutorial which covers this kind of thing? Not had any luck searching, but maybe im wording the search wrong. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: First thought is to UV unwrap the Faces the gold will be on and ensure they all over lap(so they will get the same result). Then use Texture paint mode to create the result. Use the resulting image as both the Diffuse Colour and as Bump map. You could also create a Curve and design the Gold as a separate entity with its own material and then Join or parent it to the hexa-ring.

Comment: Thank you Rob, Not being one to sit back and wait, i went ahead and did the latter, made a separate entity, i haven't parented it to the hex as yet but i think it looks good so far. Can't figure out how to post the image of progress here though.

Comment: You should edit your original question and use the standard image process.